Bootstrap-Icons with Npm, Webpack and Sass
I don't know if I'm too stupid and if I miss something, but I'm trying to use bootstrap-icons in my project and no solution I found is solving my issue...
In my project I use npm, webpack and sass. The documentation of bootstrap-icons just tells me to install bootstrap-icons with npm i bootstrap-icons. When I want to use icons with the icon font method, the documentation says:

Include the icon web fonts in your page via CSS, then reference the class names as needed in your HTML (e.g., <i class="bi-alarm-clock"></i>).

As a result I only see empty squares instead of the icons. I assume it's because the font file is not referenced / copied correctly. I see an error message, that the woff-file couldn't be found. I think it's because of the hash that is created by webpack. But I can't find out how to copy the woff-files with webpack correctly. They don't appear in the folder.
As a workaround I manually copied the woff files from node_modules directory to src/css/fonts in my project and then copy them with webpack to my dist folder. And this worked.
I already searched the web and tried a lot of things I found here or on other websites, but nothing worked for me. Always an 404 error in console for the woff files (with hashes).
Any hints for me why I'm too stupid to get this working?

This question is similar to: Bootstrap icons and Webpack 5 - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
